# Run left join using EfCore7 using `SqlQueryRaw` Function

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I Need to run a simple left join on my database and it seems EFCore cannot do this job. I have this Query:

```
"SELECT ag.ID as AgreementId, " +
            "       sg.SignedAt ," +
            "       sg.SignedByName As SignedBy," +
            "       ag.Type As Type," +
            "      ag.Version," +
            "      sg.VendorId," +
            "      ag.CreatedAt As AgreementCreated " +
            "from `Agreements` ag LEFT JOIN `SignedAgreements` sg on " +
            "     sg.`AgreementId`= ag.`Id` " +
            "    and sg.`VendorId` = @vendorId " +
            "where ag.`Type` = @type";
```

and I need to generate this query using Linq or run it directly on `dbContext.Database.SqlQueryRaw()`. So I attempted to translate this raw SQL to Linq but was unsuccessful. So, I was forced to run the query using the `dbContext.Database.SqlQueryRaw` but I am facing this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The element type 'VendorAgreementSignReadModel' used in 'SqlQuery' method is not natively supported by your database provider. Either use a supported element type, or use ModelConfigurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping to define a mapping for your type.

Comment: *So I attempted to translate this raw SQL to Linq but was unsuccessful* - keep trying. Query is simple. Show your model classes, and show your attempts.

Comment: Why write SQL or JOINs in LINQ at all? This is a simple 1:N relation. EF itself will generate the JOINs from the relations between the `SignedAgreement` and `Agreement` entities, eg `context.SignedAgreements.Where(sg=>sg.VendorID=123 && sg.Agreement.Type="whatever")....`. EF, like all ORMs, deals with graphs of *objects* not tables and rows. It's not a database driver or SQL generator

Comment: add your idea as an answer I will check it and inform you ASAP. but I tried many ways to generate this query using LINQ, GroupJoin and Left Join function but It failed

Comment: See the intellisense: "Creates a LINQ query based on a raw SQL query, which returns a result set of a *scalar type* natively supported by the database provider." (My emphasis). Show your attempts + class model if you want us to be able to help you any further.

Answer (score -1):

As [this](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/you-can-now-return-unmapped-types-from-raw-sql-select-statements-with-entity-framework-8) blog described this functionality is not supported until version 8 of EfCore.

Comment: What functionality?  JOINs are supported but you shouldn't even have to use any kind of JOIN. EF is an ORM, not a database driver. It's the ORM's job to generate JOINs from the relations between your entities. If you wanted all signed agreements for a vendor, all you'd have to do is `context.SignedAgreements.Where(sg=>sg.VendorID=123).Select(sg=>new {sg.Agreement.Version, sg.SignedAt,....})`